# C++ output variables from subclass types

Tags: c++, printing, subclass, overwrite

I'm writing a program that has a method which receives a .txt file with roads, so (and now forgive my rough translations) there's a class named **Road** which has 3 attributes:

```
Road(string code, int length, int travel)
```

And two subclasses that inherit each these 3 parameters, but each have one extra:

```
Freeway(double toll)
Highway(string terrain)
```

Upon reading the file, which comes in this format...

```
ROAD1,300,190,asphalt
ROAD2,72,45,4.75
(etc...)
```

...the method detects, based on the last parameter (double or string) if it's a freeway or a highway, and creates a new instance of either of these accordingly, and sends it to an array, and reads the following line until there are no more lines to read.

This is working properly so far. However when it comes to print the parameters of the elements of the array, if I use the printing method from the Road class, I naturally get this:

```
(ROAD1,300,190)
```

Which is only natural since the class doesn't have the last parameter. However, if I print using the same method from the Freeway or Highway class, I get this output (in the case of a Highway):

```
Highway
(,-842150451, -842150451)Terrain:
```

I don't know what these values are. Plus it's not printing the terrain nor the first parameter, the code string. What am I doing wrong? Here's the code I'm using for this on both the *Road* and *Highway* classes:

```
void Road::writer(ostream &out) const {
    cout << "(" << code  << "," << length << "," << travel << ")"; 
}
```

and

```
void Highway::writer(ostream & out) const {
    out << "Highway" << endl;
    Road::writer(out);
    out << "Terrain:" << terrain << endl;
}
```

This is how I'm calling the method that outputs the roads with their parameters:

```
void TestHeader::outputRoads(){
    for(int i=0;i<ind;i++)  //ind is the number of elements of the road array
        cout<<*vecRoads[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sends it to an array"? Show that part of code. I suspect you may be bitten by [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). Also show how you call `writer`.

Comment: Meaningless comment: how come freeways have a toll? :)

Comment: @summerbulb as I said, this is a rough translation from my language to English so I was pretty sure I didn't get something right regarding that :p

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'll update the post

Comment: @summerbulb: I, for one, always wanted to know why we drive on a parkway, and park on a driveway.

Comment: Does `Highway` constructor call `Road` constructor in its initializer list? It seems that the `Road` subobject of `Highway` simply remains uninitialized, hence empty name and garbage values for `length` and `travel`.

Comment: Goes beyond me lol, anyway I've updated the post, but I'm not sure if it's much help. I'm looking into the object slicing subject and it might perhaps be something the likes of that. In my superclass I have indeed no space for extra parameters. How could this be resolved?

Comment: Highway::Highway(string code,int length,int travel, string terrain):Road(code,length,travel)
{
 this->terrain=terrain;
}

Comment: Please post enough code that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: You've only shown how you call `operator<<`. Where and how does `writer` get into the picture? [This works for me](http://ideone.com/3YNHhb); figure out what you are doing differently.

Answer (score 0):

### Make sure that you initialize

As stated in the title, when you initialize your `Freeway` or `Highway` you should call the `Road` constructor.

e.g.

```
Highway::Highway(std::string code, int length, int travel, std::string terrain)
    : Road(code, length, travel){

    this->terrain = terrain; // Arguments shouldn't have the same name as class memebers
}
```

#### Change this

```
void Road::writer(std::ostream &out) const{
    std::cout << "(" << code  << "," << length << "," << travel << ")";
}
```

to this

```
void Road::writer(std::ostream &out) const{
    out << "(" << code  << "," << length << "," << travel << ")";
}
```

or this

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const Road &road){
    out << "(" << road.code  << "," << road.length << "," << road.travel << ")";
    // However you want to get the members

    return out;
}
```

with the operator overloading you can simplify your operations to

```
void Highway::writer(ostream & out) const {
    out << "Highway\n" << *dynamic_cast<Road*>(this) << "Terrain: " << terrain << "\n";
}
```

#### EDIT:

On second look, your last function shouldn't even work without operator overloading.
C++ doesn't know what to do with an object when you try to output it to a stream unless an operator is overloaded doe stream output.

```
void TestHeader::outputRoads(){
    for(int i = 0; i < ind; i++)  //ind is the number of elements of the road array
        std::cout << *vecRoads[i] << std::endl;
}
```

won't work without overloading
BUT

```
void TestHeader::outputRoads(){
    for(int i = 0; i < ind; i++)  //ind is the number of elements of the road array
        *vecRoads[i].writer(std::cout);
}
```

would work with the `writer` function